# can't add gem "devise" to ruby ​on rails 6 project

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, bcrypt, ruby-on-rails-6

When I included gem devise in my project and wrote the `bundle install` command to the console, in order to install all the gems in my project, I got the following error:

```
An error occurred while installing bcrypt (3.1.19), and Bundler cannot
continue.

In Gemfile:
  devise was resolved to 4.9.2, which depends on
    bcrypt
```

To solve this problem, it is enough to install or update xcode with the

```
xcode-select --install
```

command, the fact is that xcode contains some components that bcrypt needs for adequate operation, and most importantly, adequate installation.

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: It sounds like you're answering your own question? You can post the second half as an "answer" (and self-accept the solution) instead of leaving it as part of the question.

Comment: Also, I'd suggest providing more context on the error. Was there more information than just *"An error occurred while installing bcrypt"*?